# Are these Fail2Ban, Munin and “Failed password” related questions more appropriate for Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, migration

While I spend a good chunk of time here on Super User, my day-to-day/work-a-day head is in the Linux server administration world. A lot of times there’s overlap between “power user” needs and server administration skills. And many times I forget that some of that some of questions—and some self-answered questions—I have posted on Super User are a really a tad off topic for Super User… Or are they?

Specifically I posted these three questions in the past week; two are self-answered and one I genuinely need some help on:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/991437/how-can-i-upgrade-fail2ban-in-ubuntu-12-04-5-lts-to-get-the-recidive-filter-in
2. https://superuser.com/questions/994198/fail2ban-plug-in-is-enabled-in-munin-but-the-graph-images-are-broken-how-to-fix
3. https://superuser.com/questions/994373/how-can-i-combine-two-commands-to-tally-data-from-compressed-and-uncompressed-lo

The first question is about installing an upgraded version of Fail2Ban on Ubuntu 12.04.5, the next is about getting Munin graphs to generate for Fail2Ban and the last—most recent—is about combining some log tallying commands into one command.

So my question: In retrospect, are these questions appropriate for Super User? Or are they better suited for Server Fault? My gut tells me that Server Fault would be a better fit for these questions, but we do occasionally see some server-ish questions here on Super User so perhaps they should stay here?

For example, the tags on Super User for [Fail2Ban](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fail2ban) and [Munin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/munin) are barely used for anything of any signifcance. In contrast the tags for [Fail2Ban](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fail2ban) and [Munin](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/munin) on Server Fault are filled with content. Should I interpret that as the Super User tags are underused and should possibly be reviewed for deletion or perhaps those tags should have more and better content attached to them to help them grow?

This is not asking for a consensus at all but maybe some wisdom from those who have been here longer than me. Should these three questions be moved? And for the record, I’m completely fine with a moderator moving these to Server Fault if that makes the most sense.

***UPDATE:*** Decided to vote to close my questions for migration to Server Fault. That said, if someone feels like explaining how these questions might fit on Super User, please feel free to post your thoughts in an answer.

Comment: It's a really hard call. Is this in a production server environment?

Comment: There are two purposes for any questions and answers: get the OP an answer, and help others with a similar question.  At this point, all of the benefit will be to others.  Post them where they will do the most good.  If you suspect, from the tag usage, that more people will be looking on SF, migrate them there.  Don't hide your brilliance here.  :-)

Comment: @JakeGould Flagged as per your request ;)

Comment: Voted to close on all three. We just need one more vote...